# IDE Error Occured при создании нового проекта Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

При создании нового проекта на котлин в Android Studio 3.6.3 всгда выдает одну и ту же ошибку:

> IDE Error Occured

В окне подробностей в заголовке написано Exception in plugin Android Support. 
Далее идет отчет exception report:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.submitTransactionAndWait(TransactionGuardImpl.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:249)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$BuilderImpl.compute(WriteCommandAction.java:137)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewModuleModel$ModuleTemplateRenderer.render(NewModuleModel.kt:195)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer$countDown$2.invoke(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:132)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.MultiTemplateRenderer$countDown$2.invoke(MultiTemplateRenderer.kt:37)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1$1.run(NewProjectModel.kt:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.NonProjectFileWritingAccessProvider.disableChecksDuring(NonProjectFileWritingAccessProvider.java:174)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:110)
    at com.android.tools.idea.npw.model.NewProjectModel$multiTemplateRenderer$1$$special$$inlined$run$lambda$1.invoke(NewProjectModel.kt:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidNewProjectInitializationStartupActivity.runActivity(AndroidNewProjectInitializationStartupActivity.kt:41)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runActivity(StartupManagerImpl.java:205)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.lambda$runPostStartupActivitiesFromExtensions$2(StartupManagerImpl.java:172)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionPointImpl.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointImpl.java:321)
    at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.ExtensionPointName.processWithPluginDescriptor(ExtensionPointName.java:140)
    at com.intellij.ide.startup.impl.StartupManagerImpl.runPostStartupActivitiesFromExtensions(StartupManagerImpl.java:170)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.impl.ProjectManagerImpl.lambda$null$8(ProjectManagerImpl.java:411)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:253)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:894)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:169)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:591)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:156)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$9(ApplicationImpl.java:552)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.createNewEntry(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:94)
    at com.intellij.xml.arrangement.XmlArrangementVisitor.visitXmlTag(XmlArrangementVisitor.java:52)
```

Что пробовал сделать:

1. File=>Invalidate Caches/Restart....
2. Clean Project / Rebuild Project
3. Переустановка Java

Ничего из этого не помогло. Старые проекты (которые буквально позавчера создал) открываются а новые создаваться не могут. Подскажите, как можно решить проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

В `build.gradle(:project)` добавь:

В блок `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"
}
```

В `build.gradle(:app)` добавь:

В самом верху файла

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

В блок `dependencies`

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.72"
}
```